# summernote codeview copy with jquery

Tags: jquery, editor, summernote

I am using summernote Editor and it show the HTML code by clicking the codeview button.

Whether I open codeview or not, I want to make a button that copies(like ctrl + c) codeview HTML code.

Can I access that code in the editor with jquery?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.